# Key-value storage for counters with ability of fast dumping data

Tags: php, redis, storage, counter, key-value

Let's imagine that, we have 300K keys with simple counters in our storage Counter key names, for example:

`counter1_2014-03-25_00:01
counter2_2014-03-25_00:01 
counter3_2014-03-25_00:01`

Each counter is collecting data for 1 minute, thus one key per one minute: `counter1_2014-03-25_00:01, counter1_2014-03-25_00:02, counter1_2014-03-25_00:03 etc.`

Every next minute I have to dump all counters for previous minute and remove them from storage. My current implementation is really really simple and using Redis hashes (`HINCR, HGETALL, DEL`).

`//incrementing counter
$Redis->hincr('counters_2014-03-25_00:02', 'counter1');`

`//dumping and removing
$result = $Redis->multi() 
                ->hgetall('counters_2014-03-25_00:02') //dumping
                ->del('counters_2014-03-25_00:02')     //removing hash
                ->exec()`

Everything is fine with Redis, but dumping with `HGETALL` is getting very and very slow with large number of counters because `HGETALL` have `O(N)` complexity.

Right now I'm looking for approach that will allow:

- atomically incremented counters doing as fast as Redis do
- quickly dump counter values collected for previous minute
- remove counters collected for previous minute from storage
- no 100% persistence required, but it will be a great plus

**UPDATE:** Fast dumping is required because I need to transfer all locally collected data from backend servers to master server.

Comment: Have you tried doing the cleanup server-side in a Lua script? You can dump to one Redis key.

Comment: @TwBert, excellent idea! I have to think about it. How do you see it?

Comment: Before I can come up with a good answer, I need some more info. How are the counters distributed? Is it counter1 to counter999999 without gaps? Does each minute in time have a counter entry or are there gaps? How many counters each hour? Do the clients have something like a session ID? Maybe a PID is unique enough, or is it multi-server?

Comment: Forget that last remark about session ID, not relevant. But do give a description of the data you want collected before deletion. Is a nested structure of `[id, [minute-timestamp=hits]]` enough?

Comment: @TwBert, hash looks like `[199_114_GB_android=55, 255_32_DE_iphone=50, 112_123_RU_other=25] etc.`. Counter key (counter id) are built by pattern `PlacementId_BannerId_GEO_Platform`. Hash key name is `impressions_20140701_20:11`. So, every hash contains data only for one minute. Different minute-hashes contains different number of hashes. Structure you've provided `[id, [minute-timestamp=hits]] is not suitable for this task, right now I have structure hash_1minute=[counter1=hits,counter2=hits,counter3=hits].

Comment: Can you give me an idea of the amount of data that is generated each minute? How many counters/how many increments per counter? You mention the `O(N)` complexity as a problem, but this is not the issue. If you need all data, you need it. N hash members is N times as much data compared to 1 hash member, hence O(N). Redis can't do magic for you... So it might be more of a storage issue than a retrieval issue. Just thinking along...

Comment: @TwBert, Each minute is generated about 100-150K rows in hash. About ~1600 incerements per second per all counters. On RedisDb google group I was suggested to use HSCAN instead of HGETALL, HSCAN can scan hash by pages, for example by 10K items. I haven't tried it yet, but I'm planning to do it soon.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about advising you `HSCAN` as well. The total time it takes will be the same (or a bit more), but you don't hinder your other clients this way. Gives it some air. Ask again if you get stuck, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to create simple keys, increment using INCR and each time you create a key set an expiry time with it using EXPIRE.